# Counting variables values from $_REQUEST

Tags: php

My $_REQUEST is the below

```
Array
(
    [city] => Antalya
    [country] => Turcia
    [DesinationId] => A99O
    [In] => 2015-04-29
    [Out] => 2015-05-01
    [rooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 2
                    [child] => 0
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 1
                    [child] => 0
                )

        )

    [PHPSESSID] => 195897227bcf5ff2772632d7063b7ba7
    [_ga] => GA1.2.45498464.1425755756
)
```

I am trying to count the adults and childs from both rooms

```
$adults = ($_REQUEST->rooms[0]->adult + $_REQUEST->rooms[2]->adult)
```

but the result is 0 , Any ideea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$adults = ($_REQUEST['rooms'][0]['adult'] + $_REQUEST['rooms'][2]['adults']);
```

well `$_REQUEST` is not instance of `stdClass`, it's an array, so you can access it like an array